# On Measurability of random variable

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I am studying measurability of r.v. and I am trying to answer the following question.

Suppose $X: \Omega \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ has a countable range $\mathcal{R}$. Show $X \in \mathcal{B}/\mathcal{B}({\mathbb{R}})$ (measurable) iff 
\begin{align*}
X^{-1}(\{x\}) \in  \mathcal{B}, \, \forall x \in \mathcal{R}.
\end{align*}

Showing that $X \in \mathcal{B}/\mathcal{B}({\mathbb{R}})$ implies $X^{-1}(\{x\}) \in  \mathcal{B}, \, \forall x \in \mathcal{R}$ is rather straight forward. What about the other direction?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: 20+ months on the site, 60+ questions asked, and you cannot do better than that?

Comment: I am Sorry. you don't like my question?

Comment: Have you ever tried to read a howtoask page on the site?

Comment: Tell me what I did wrong and I will correct it?

Comment: What you hadn't done is more interesting (as you are well aware), but if you want me to spell it for you although you know it, here it comes: you had posted the statement of an exercise without any personal input. By the way, how do you call adding a paragraph explaining the problem you have with the math question (after I asked for it) and, **then**, asking that people explain what you did wrong: disingenuous, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realize that $X^{-1}(B)$ can be written as $\bigcup_{x\in\mathcal R\cap B}X^{-1}(\{x\})$ wich is a *countable* union of measurable sets.

That means that $X^{-1}(B)$ is measurable itself.

---

**edit**:

$$\omega\in X^{-1}\left(B\right)\iff X\left(\omega\right)\in B\iff X\left(\omega\right)\in B\cap\mathcal{R}\iff\exists x\in B\cap\mathcal{R}\left[X\left(\omega\right)=x\right]$$$$\iff\exists x\in B\cap\mathcal{R}\left[\omega\in X^{-1}\left(\left\{ x\right\} \right)\right]\iff\omega\in\bigcup_{x\in B\cap\mathcal{R}}X^{-1}\left(\left\{ x\right\} \right)$$

Comment: when you say $B$ you means sigma algebra? Or just any set in sigma algebra?

Comment: No, I mean a Borel-subset of $\mathbb R$

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain why $X^{-1}(B)$ can be write as you said?

Comment: actually I think I get it now. A picture helped. Thanks you very much?

Comment: You are welcome. Also see my edit.